# Data can not insert into form(php)

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

> ERROR: Could not able to execute 
>   `INSERT INTO ms(group, rollno , obtmarks , totalmarks, board, passyear, division)VALUES('Science' , '6787' , '723' , '1100' , 'islambad' , '2012' , '1st')`. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your harisDB server version for the right syntax to use `near 'group, rollno , obtmarks , totalmarks, board, passyear, division)VALUES('S' at line 1!`

[Image of form displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UDap.jpg)

Comment: Need to see the php code.

Comment: show me your table structure and inserting php code

Comment: group is a reserved word in mysql. use other name for a column instead of group.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO ms(groups, rollno , obtmarks , totalmarks, board, passyear, division)VALUES('Science' , '6787', '723', '1100', 'islambad', '2012', '1st');`

Please try above query. Instead of **group change column name to groups** and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO ms(groups, rollno, obtmarks, totalmarks, board, passyear, division) VALUES('Science', '6787', '723', '1100', 'islambad', '2012', '1st');
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out `group` is a reserved word, two solutions, add back ticks round the name-

```
INSERT INTO ms(`group`, rollno , obtmarks , totalmarks, board, passyear, division) VALUES ('Science' , '6787' , '723' , '1100' , 'islambad' , '2012' , '1st')
```

(also note the extra spaces round `VALUES` to help).

**Or** rename the column.

**Also** a reminder that you should be using prepared statements and bind variables as this is more secure and safer in general.

Answer (score 0):

It's work properly

No need to change any column name just replace the below query.

```
INSERT INTO ms(`groups`, rollno , obtmarks , totalmarks, board, passyear, division)VALUES('Science' , '6787', '723', '1100', 'islambad', '2012', '1st');
```

If any other query let me know.

I hope this is helpful.

Thank You.